# Simple android app crashes on startup

Tags: java, android, xml, crash, startup

I am creating a new Android app, but it crashes on startup (phone and emulator).

Here is the code:

**Arcig Manifest.xml**

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<manifest xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    package="com.tona.arcig"
    android:versionCode="1"
    android:versionName="1.0" >

<uses-sdk
    android:minSdkVersion="15"
    android:targetSdkVersion="17" /><application android:allowBackup="true" android:icon="@drawable/ic_launcher" android:label="@string/app_name" android:theme="@style/AppTheme">
    <activity android:name="MainActivity" android:label="@string/app_name">
        <intent-filter>
            <action android:name="android.intent.action.MAIN" />

            <category android:name="android.intent.category.LAUNCHER" />
        </intent-filter>
    </activity>
</application>
```

**Strings.xml**

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<resources>

    <string name="suplovani">Suplování</string>
    <string name="rozvrh">Rozvrh hodin</string>
    <string name="prihlasovani">Přihlašování do systému</string>
    <string name="email">Email</string>
    <string name="moodle">Moodle</string>
    <string name="kdm">KDM</string>
    <string name="o_aplikaci">O Aplikaci</string>
    <string name="app_name">Arcig.CZ</string>

</resources>
```

**activity_main.xml**

```
    <LinearLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    android:layout_width="fill_parent"
    android:layout_height="fill_parent"
    android:orientation="vertical" >

    <LinearLayout
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:orientation="horizontal" >

        <ImageButton
            android:id="@+id/imageButton1"
            android:layout_width="wrap_content"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:layout_weight="2"
            android:contentDescription="@string/suplovani"
            android:src="@drawable/suplovani" />

        <ImageButton
            android:id="@+id/imageButton2"
            android:layout_width="wrap_content"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:layout_weight="2"
            android:contentDescription="@string/rozvrh"
            android:src="@drawable/rozvrh" />

    </LinearLayout>

    <LinearLayout
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content" >

        <ImageButton
            android:id="@+id/imageButton3"
            android:layout_width="wrap_content"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:layout_weight="2"
            android:contentDescription="@string/prihlasovani"
            android:src="@drawable/prihlasovani" />

        <ImageButton
            android:id="@+id/imageButton4"
            android:layout_width="wrap_content"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:layout_weight="2"
            android:contentDescription="@string/email"
            android:src="@drawable/email" />

    </LinearLayout>

    <LinearLayout
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content" >

        <ImageButton
            android:id="@+id/imageButton5"
            android:layout_width="wrap_content"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:layout_weight="2"
            android:contentDescription="@string/email"
            android:src="@drawable/moodle" />

        <ImageButton
            android:id="@+id/imageButton6"
            android:layout_width="wrap_content"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:layout_weight="2"
            android:contentDescription="@string/kdm"
            android:src="@drawable/jidelna" />

    </LinearLayout>

    <LinearLayout
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:orientation="vertical" >

        <ImageButton
            android:id="@+id/imageButton7"
            android:layout_width="wrap_content"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:contentDescription="@string/o_aplikaci"
            android:src="@drawable/about" />

    </LinearLayout>

</LinearLayout>
```

**MainActivity.java**

```
package com.tona.arcig;

import android.app.Activity;
import android.os.Bundle;
import android.view.View;
import android.widget.Button;
import android.widget.Toast;

public class MainActivity extends Activity {

    @Override
    protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        setContentView(R.layout.activity_main);

        addListenerOnButton();
    }

    public void addListenerOnButton() {

        Button button = (Button) findViewById(R.id.imageButton1);
        button.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
            public void onClick(View v) {
                // Do something in response to button click
                Toast.makeText(getApplicationContext(), "Mam rad vlaky", Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();
            }
        });
    }
}
```

**CONSOLE**

```
[2014-09-07 16:39:21 - Arcig] ------------------------------
[2014-09-07 16:39:21 - Arcig] Android Launch!
[2014-09-07 16:39:21 - Arcig] adb is running normally.
[2014-09-07 16:39:21 - Arcig] Performing com.tona.arcig.MainActivity activity launch
[2014-09-07 16:39:21 - Arcig] Automatic Target Mode: Unable to detect device compatibility. Please select a target device.
[2014-09-07 16:39:23 - Arcig] Application already deployed. No need to reinstall.
[2014-09-07 16:39:23 - Arcig] Starting activity com.tona.arcig.MainActivity on device 0123456789ABCDEFG
[2014-09-07 16:39:24 - Arcig] ActivityManager: Starting: Intent { act=android.intent.action.MAIN cat=[android.intent.category.LAUNCHER] cmp=com.tona.arcig/.MainActivity }
```

When I execute the app, it just shows a crash message. :( Can anybody help me? Have I made any mistakes in the code?
Thanks a lot guys

Comment: Can you please include the stack trace of the actual crash? It doesn't show in the console output. Also, try cleaning the project and compiling and installing again -- you may just have a stale APK installed.

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/23353173/unfortunately-myapp-has-stopped-how-can-i-solve-this

Answer (score 8, accepted):

```
<ImageButton
        android:id="@+id/imageButton1"
```

and

```
Button button = (Button) findViewById(R.id.imageButton1);
```

`ImageButton` is not a `Button` so this causes `ClassCastException` you would have seen in your logcat if you had included it in the question. (Hint: Always start crash-solving with the stacktrace in logcat.)

Change the latter part to

```
ImageButton button = (ImageButton) findViewById(R.id.imageButton1);
```

Comment: WOW!!! Many thanx! I cat get this stupid mistake! I love u! I worked on that crash for 4 hours. Many thanks

Answer (score 0):

I can see you are using ImageButton. I guess, the drawable images source size are more. If the images size are more android app will crash. Please try to keep your individual image size as low as possible. May be with in  50-60KB per image.

Comment: My size of images are max 10kB. But thanks for reply.